# Unable to connect to google APi server using python

Tags: python, google-api-python-client

Am using the below code to test the google API connectivity using python code.Imported the modules pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client.
But still getting the error.Would like somebody to help on this

```
   from __future__ import print_function
    from apiclient import discovery
    import apiclient.discovery

    TMPL = '''
        User: %s
        Date: %s
        Post: %s
    '''

    API_KEY = "my key" # copied from project credentials page
    print (type (API_KEY))

    GPLUS = apiclient.discovery.build('plus', 'v1', developerKey=API_KEY)

    items = GPLUS.activities().search(query='python').execute().get('items', [])
    for data in items:
        post = ' '.join(data['title'].strip().split())
        if post:
            print(TMPL % (data['actor']['displayName'],
                          data['published'], post))
```

Getting the below error ,
     File "", line 1, in 
        runfile('D:/Mohana/Python/scripts/Google_PlusTest1.py', wdir='D:/Mohana/Python/scripts')

```
  File "C:\Users\1234\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 710, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\1234\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 101, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "D:/Mohana/Python/scripts/Google_PlusTest1.py", line 21, in <module>
    GPLUS = apiclient.discovery.build('plus', 'v1', developerKey=API_KEY)

  File "C:\Users\1234\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\_helpers.py", line 133, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\1234\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\discovery.py", line 229, in build
    requested_url, discovery_http, cache_discovery, cache)

  File "C:\Users\1234\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\discovery.py", line 276, in _retrieve_discovery_doc
    resp, content = http.request(actual_url)

  File "C:\Users\1234\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\httplib2\__init__.py", line 1322, in request
    (response, content) = self._request(conn, authority, uri, request_uri, method, body, headers, redirections, cachekey)

  File "C:\Users\1234\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\httplib2\__init__.py", line 1072, in _request
    (response, content) = self._conn_request(conn, request_uri, method, body, headers)

  File "C:\Users\1234\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\httplib2\__init__.py", line 1002, in _conn_request
    raise ServerNotFoundError("Unable to find the server at %s" % conn.host)

ServerNotFoundError: Unable to find the server at www.googleapis.com
```